# Where is the .apk file output after signing it via Azure android signing build pipeline?

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, apk, azure-pipelines

I'm signing an apk file in a build pipeline using the Azure 'Android Signing' task but I cannot see the path in which the signed apk is output to. I've exported the entire root of the build pipeline as .zip file, but a signed .apk file does not exist. What's even more confusing is that the Android Signing task is **passing**, so the signed .apk must be somewhere right? The question is where!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android Signing' task did not create a new apk. The signed apk is still in the output folder of android build task.
If you use XamarinAndroid task to build your apk. The .apk will be output to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` for below example:  Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for all predefined variables

```
- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*droid*.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Then you can add the android sign task and point apkFiles to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.apk` for below example:

```
- task: AndroidSigning@3
  inputs:
    apksign: true
    zipalign: false
    apksignerKeystoreFile: levi.keystore
    apkFiles: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.apk'
    keystoreAlias: levi
    apksignerKeyPassword: '**'
    apksignerKeystorePassword: '**'
```

You can then add a publish artifacts task to publish your apk to azure server,where you can download from azure devops build summary UI when your build is complete.

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'.
```

Then you can download the apk from your build summary page.
[image]

You can run below command to check if the apk is signed or not after you downloaded it from azure server.

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

Comment: I see, thanks for this answer. However I am using gradle to build my apk - does this work in the same way? Aka/ is my apk now signed if I point the signing task towards the apk created by gradle build

Comment: Yes if the signing task is pointed the apk created by gradle. It should be signed. You can run this command against your apk after you downloaded to your local place,To double check if the apk is signed.  `$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk`

Comment: If you are using an alternative framework like cordova/phonegap or Xamarin it might have a `myapp-release-unsigned.apk` as the name of your APK. You can pass apkSigner arguments to tell it to use a different `--out` path to create a new/separate SIGNED apk like `--out myapp-signed.apk`.

Comment: Also see my question please https://stackoverflow.com/q/76819786/4134215