# .apk file not generated using xamarin-android task in azure pipeline

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-devops, apk

I am trying to generate the `.apk` file for `Xamarin` forms project using xamarin. Android task in azure pipeline. But `.apk` file not generated. Instead in artifact I can see the folder structure is getting copied as it is for the Project.
App Center is successfully generating the `.apk` using same project. But not working with azure pipeline.

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?Could you find .apk file now? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

The signed apk is in the output folder of android build task. If you use XamarinAndroid task to build your apk. The .apk will be output to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` for below example, you can check the `.apk` file there.

```
- task: XamarinAndroid@1
  inputs:
    projectFile: '**/*droid*.csproj'
    outputDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

`Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory`: The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination. For example: `c:\agent_work\1\a`.
You can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) for all predefined variables.

You can refer to this similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58839588/where-is-the-apk-file-output-after-signing-it-via-azure-android-signing-build-p) for details .

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, verify that the configuration is set to apk:

[image: Android Package Type]

For me it seems the default for the Debug configuration was .apk, but for Release it was 'bundle' - therefore generating the .apk on my PC but .aab in the Azure pipeline.